# MP line chart - Unable to plot area on line chart with XY Axis limits

Tags: mpandroidchart

Any one help me to achieve the following chart

[Click here to view full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGmEk.png)

Comment: The line in the middle looks like a LimitLine. Im not sure about the rest of the chart. The red line with the fab button looks custom to me.

Comment: This is not a specific programming question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic